# Is there a way to generate Jest / Istanbul coverage report in junit.xml format

Tags: xml, junit, jestjs, gitlab-ci, istanbul

I'd like to use Gitlab CI for tracking / embedding the coverage analysis in merge requests. The [`gitlab-ci.yml artifacts:reports:junit`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactsreports) config option seems to be suitable for this task. However, this requires the **coverage** 
 output to be in junit.xml format.

I don't find a proper setup for outputting the coverage  this format. Neither can I find a tool to convert from lcov/json/clover to junit.xml .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done with the jest-junit reporter plugin. https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit

```
yarn add --dev jest-junit
```

Then execute this locally to see if it is working

```
yarn test --colors --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit
```

And you'll see a junit.xml file in root.

Configure your .gitlab-ci.yml like this to then see the output in Gitlab:

```
test:
  stage: test
  coverage: /All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: junit.xml
  script:
    - yarn test --colors --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit
```

Oh and add the coverage/ folder and junit.xml to .gitignore so they aren't added to the git repo.

This all seems to work ok in a Create React App project too